# Jersey 2 REST Client - Read Multipart Response / OctetStream Response

Tags: java, jersey-2.0

I'm building a Jersey 2 client, which calls a service to get a file from the server.

The service returns binary file content as application/octet-stream

NOw, this is my code where I call the webservice

```
Response response = target.request().header(HttpHeaders.COOKIE, this.cookie)
                   .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)     
                   .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM).get();
```

I get a HTTP 200 Response. But i don't understand how I can get the file content from the response.

**EDIT**
The service documentation says "To GET the binary file content and the metadata, use header Accept: multipiart/mixed"

So, I tried the below

```
        Response response = target.request()
                            .header(HttpHeaders.COOKIE, this.cookie)
                            .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, "multipart/mixed")
                            .accept("multipart/mixed").get();
```

Even here, I get a HTTP status 200 response. But How do I read the file content??

Please help!!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [documentation](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/user-guide.html#d0e4669) you will see that response has a readEntity method that you can use to read the inputstream:

```
InputStream in = response.readEntity(InputStream.class);
... // Read from the stream
in.close();
```